# Make Hotkey Alt plus 2 or more letters/numbers

Tags: autohotkey

I wish to use AutoHotKey to generate some text based on a combination of a Alt key press plus 2 or more characters ...for example hold Alt key down then press 23 and the result would be some text string pasted into the editor...

I know how to do this for Alt  plus 1 character, but not multiple characters ...example:

```
!1::
send Hello
return
```

Uses Alt plus the number 1 to generate the string **Hello** ...I would like to be able to use Alt plus 1A or Alt plus CB to cause the string to be generated ...is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many many ways this can be achieved, some come with more downsides then others.
One really simple way that has pretty minimal downsides is utilizing `A_PriorHotkey`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#PriorHotkey)</sup> to make a [context sensitive hotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Context) with `#If`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm)</sup> like so:

```
!2::return
!2 up::return

#If, A_PriorHotkey == "!2"
!3::SendInput, hello
#If
```

The `!2` and `!2 up` hotkeys are there just to a value to `A_PriorHotkey`.
The downside here is of course losing the native functionality of <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>.
Further trickery could be added in so the <sub><sup>(at least almost)</sup></sub> native functionality of <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> could be kept as well. But I won't speculate of any of the finer details and edge cases on how you'd want these multi-combination hotkeys to work. You'd have to clearly state that yourself.